# How to retain all occurrences of X when using the greedy quantifier X* in a java regexp?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a regular expression that I use to find matches of a list of coma-separated words between <> inside a string, like `"Hello <a1> sqjsjqk <b1,b2> dsjkfjkdsf <c1,c2,c3> ffsd"` in the example

I want to use capturing groups to retain each word between the braces:

Here is my expression: `<  (\w+)  (?:  ,(\w+)  )*  >` (spaces are added for readability but not a part of the pattern)

Parenthesis are for creating capturing groups, `(?:      )` is for creating a non capturing group, because I don't want to retain the coma.

Here is my test code:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String patternString = "<(\\w+)(?:,(\\w+))*>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello <a1> sqjsjqk <b1,b2> dsjkfjkdsf <c1,c2,c3> ffsd");
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("== Match ==");
        MatchResult matchResult = matcher.toMatchResult();
        for(int i = 0; i < matchResult.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("  " + matchResult.group(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output produced:

```
== Match ==
  a1
  null
== Match ==
  b1
  b2
== Match ==
  c1
  c3
```

And here is what I wanted:

```
== Match ==
  a1
== Match ==
  b1
  b2
== Match ==
  c1
  c2
  c3
```

From this I understand that there is exactly as many groups as the number of capturing groups in my expression, but this is not what I want, because I need all the substring that were recognized as the  `\w+`

Is there any chance to get what I want with a single RegExp, or should I finish the job with `split(",")`, `trim()`, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know .NET has the only regex engine out there, that can return multiple captures for a single capturing group. So what you are asking for is not possible in Java  (at least not the way you asked for).

In your case this problem can however be solved to a certain extent. If you can be sure that there will never be an unmatched closing `>`, you can make the stuff you want to capture the full match, and require the correct position through a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"\\w+(?=(?:,\\w+)*>)"
```

This can never match "words" outside of `<...>`, because they cannot get past the opening `<` to match the closing `>`. Of course that makes it hard to distinguish between elements from different sets of `<...>`.

Alternatively (and I suppose that is even better, because it's safer, and more readable), go for a two-step algorithm. First match

```
"<([\\w,]*)>"
```

Then `split` every result's first capture at `,`.

Comment: I'll take option 2 because of ", and more readable", which should also be mensionned. Thanks

Comment: @SamuelRossille mentioned it ;)